# Unix permission denied

Tags: unix, system-verilog

I use the vcs to compile a lot of SystemVerilog files and `-o directory` to output the result in the directory. (My friend helped me to solve this problem before but once I restart the computer it appears again). If it's correct, after the compile, I could use `./simv -gui` to use the DVE and check the correctness of my code.

Now the result shows that several `g++: error: ...: Permission denied`:

> g++: error: _23220_archive_1.so: Permission denied
>       g++: error: _csrc0.so: Permission denied
>       g++: error: _csrc0.so: Permission denied
>       Makefile:97: recipe for target 'product_timestamp' failed
>       make: *** [product_timestamp] Error 1
>       Make exited with status 2

The csrc is the output file name (`.../build/csrc`).

I tried to debug it with the `chmod -R 775 "directory"` command but it still does not work. Attached is the result and the errors.
Thanks!

Comment: Did someone previously run a compile under another user id?  `ls -l` the object files and check who owns them and the directory that they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Probably FS where your directory is located mounts with -noexec option. `pwd` and `mount` should confirm or disprove my guess. If it's true, fix it by removing noexec from specific FS mount in /etc/fstab